# Angular Unit Testing - httpBackend JSONP

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I have spent way too much time on this. I have a simple angular app that gets some JSONP from a remote server and displays that on the screen.

I am having the hardest time creating a unit test for it with Jasmine.

Here is my App

```
var pdApp = angular.module('pdApp', []);
pdApp.controller('pdController', function ($scope, $http) {

  var jsonpUrl = "http://10.1.20.377/products/1/167?cb=JSON_CALLBACK";


  $http.jsonp(jsonpUrl).success(function(data) {

    $scope.pageContent = data.pageContent;
    $scope.cartContent = data.cartContent;
    $scope.content = data.productContent;

  });

});
```

And here is my unit test

```
describe('myTest', function () {

  var MainCtrl, scope, httpBackend;

  beforeEach(module('pdApp'));

  module('pdApp', function($provide) {
    $provide.value('DefaultContent', defaultJSON);
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $httpBackend) {
    httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    MainCtrl = $controller('pdController', {
        $scope: scope
    });
  }));


   it("Product name should be set", function(){
     httpBackend.whenJSONP("/products/1/167").respond(
        {
            "name" : "Prod Name",
            "desc" : "Long Description Here"

        }
     );
     expect(scope.pageContent.name).toEqual("Prod Name");
   });


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice that you forgot the `httpBackend.flush();`, so the response will not flush out.

Comment: @bencripps From the [document](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend): "the mock $httpBackend has a flush() method, which allows the test to explicitly flush pending requests. This preserves the async api of the backend, while allowing the test to execute synchronously."